# Discrete probability problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

**Problem:**

Assume the number of cars passing a road crossing during an hour satisfies a Poisson distribution with parameter $\mu$, and that the number of passengers in each car satisfies a binomial distribution with parameters $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $p \in (0,1)$. Let $Y$ denote the total number of passengers passing the road crossing during an hour. Compute $\mathbb{E}[Y]$ and Var$(Y)$.

**My thoughts:**

If we let $X_i$ be the number of passengers in the $i^{\text{th}}$ car, we have that $$\mathbb{E}[Y]= \sum_{i=1}^N \mathbb{E}[X_i], $$
where $N$ is the total number of cars. Since $X_i$ ~ Binomial$(n,p)$, $\mathbb{E}[X_i]=np$ $\hspace{1mm}$ $\forall$ $i \in \mathbb{N}$. Furthermore, since $N$ ~ Poisson$(\mu)$, we have $\mathbb{E}[N]=\mu$, yielding $\mathbb{E}[Y]=\mu np.$

This *seems* right, but I'm dissatisfied with the lack of thoroughness with my argument. Any ideas?

(Edit: This isn't homework.)

Comment: Read about compound Poisson: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_distribution

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing the first is using conditioned probability.  $N$ and $X_i$ are both random (independent) variables. Now, what you computed first is actually the conditional expectation:

$$E[Y|N] = \sum_{i=1}^N E(X_i) = N n p$$

but $E[Y] = E[ E[Y | N]]$ ([ref](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation); the outer expectation is with respect of N) then we get $E[Y] = E (N n p) = np E(N) = n p \mu$

A similar argument can be used to compute $E(Y^2)$ (and hence the variance). Or you can read
about the Compound Poisson distribution and its [properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_distribution#Properties).

Comment: Great. I thought I was (mis-)using conditional expectation somehow. This clears it up. Thanks!

Comment: I've computed the variance (see below). I don't think we need to compute $E(Y^2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Calculating Var$(Y)$ using leonbloy's suggestion of the use of law of total expectation:

First, note that $$\text{Var}(Y|N)=\sum_{i=1}^N \text{Var}(X_i) = Nnp(1-p).$$
Now, by the [law of total variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance), we have 
$$\begin{align*}
\text{Var}(Y) &= \mathbb{E}[\text{Var}(Y|N)]+\text{Var}(\mathbb{E}[Y|N]) \\ &= \mathbb{E}[Nnp(1-p)]+\text{Var}(Nnp) \\ 
&= np(1-p)\mathbb{E}[N]+n^2p^2Var(N) \\ &=np(1-p)\mu+n^2p^2\mu.
\end{align*}$$